# array misinterpretation in SOAP communication

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl

I have a java webserver that I need to communicate with using a wsdl contract. I didn't built the server, and I don't have access to its source code. I built a c# application and I added the service reference to the wsdl contract using visual studio "add service reference". I paste the part of the wsdl I am interested in:

```
<wsdl:operation name="SOAPRequestItemHead" parameterOrder="SessionID searchitems">
  <wsdl:input message="impl:SOAPRequestItemHeadRequest" name="SOAPRequestItemHeadRequest"/>
  <wsdl:output message="impl:SOAPRequestItemHeadResponse" name="SOAPRequestItemHeadResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="SOAPRequestItemHead">
  <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
  <wsdl:input name="SOAPRequestItemHeadRequest">
    <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://wrapper.soap.aplusb.com" use="encoded"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output name="SOAPRequestItemHeadResponse">
    <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://192.168.200.26:8888/tcdnc/services/fsw" use="encoded"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:message name="SOAPRequestItemHeadResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="SOAPRequestItemHeadReturn" type="tns2:SOAPItemRevisionHeadResult"/>
</wsdl:message>
<complexType name="SOAPItemRevisionHeadResult">
  <sequence>
    <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="comment" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="searchComplete" type="xsd:boolean"/>
    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="search" type="tns2:StringMap"/>
    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="resultList" type="tns2:SOAPItemRevisionHead"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Note that `resultList` and `search` are arrays. If I call this method, here is the raw response, taken with a SOAP tool:

```
<SOAPRequestItemHeadReturn xmlns:ns2="fsw" xsi:type="ns2:SOAPItemRevisionHeadResult">
  <comment xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
  <searchComplete xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</searchComplete>
  <resultList xsi:type="ns2:SOAPItemRevisionHead">
    <search xsi:type="ns2:StringMap">
      <stringKey xsi:type="xsd:string">ItemRevision.ItemID</stringKey>
      <stringValue xsi:type="xsd:string">cam_english_template</stringValue>
    </search>
    <search xsi:type="ns2:StringMap">
      <stringKey xsi:type="xsd:string">ItemRevision.Revision</stringKey>
      <stringValue xsi:type="xsd:string">A</stringValue>
    </search>
    <dummy xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
  </resultList>
  <resultList xsi:type="ns2:SOAPItemRevisionHead">
...
```

As you see, `resultList` and `search` are actually arrays. But when I call the method from my c# client, I get this error:

> Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'SOAPRequestItemHead'.
>
> Inner Exception: There is an error in XML document (1, 815).
>
> Inner Exception: Cannot assign object of type StringMap to an object of type StringMap[]

And if I go to the `Reference.cs` that is automatically generated, and I manually change the type of the two properties that are supposed to be arrays from `StringMap[]` to `StringMap` the error is not thrown, but of course I can only get the first item of the array in my program. I hope I was clear, even if it's a long question.

Update: I know this is a problem with using Axis 1.4, that uses rcp/encoded instead of document/literal, so the question can be reformulated in these terms: "can .NET correctly handle rcp/encoded?"

Comment: So far the only answer I found is the "hard one", I mean, manually remove "[]" from imported Reference.cs. I hate to do this but it works.

Comment: But, as I said, I only see the first element. That's not OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data contracts generated by VS. They should contain specific type for the 'resultList' as well, decorated with `CollectionDataContract` attribute. I would also check whether the namespaces and names are set precisely on `DataContract` attributes.

EDIT: about RPC style web services you can find some workaround on these links:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/51babae5-26e5-4405-b03c-4301710854c0/why-does-add-service-reference-fail-to-build-a-proper-reference-for-dfa?forum=wcf
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/07edda1a-d0d5-4920-b2fb-a25c803269d6/trouble-with-consuming-a-java-rpc-web-service-using-net-client?forum=wcf

Comment: In `public partial class SOAPItemRevisionHeadResult` I have `public SOAPItemRevisionHead[] resultList`. I have to delete the array brackets to get it to work, but, as I said, I can only retrieve the first element. It doesn't have the `CollectionDataContract` attribute. The class has the `System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute` and the property doesn't have parameters. And this applies for pretty much all the classes in the reference.cs. How should I modify the attributes?

Comment: Oh.. you are using old-school web reference. Sorry, for some reason I thought you were using WCF. Then does it have a XmlArrayAttribute and XmlArrayItemAttribute? How does the corresponding part of the generated class look like?

Comment: I am not using web reference, I am using wcf, why do you think i am using webreference? (BTW, I also tried with web reference, but no luck)

Comment: As far as I know, System.Xml.Serialization is used by web references, service references (WCF) use System.ServiceModel for serialization. That's why I thought you were using a web reference instead of a service reference. A web reference is generated by choosing: Add Service Reference/Advanced/Add Web Reference.

Comment: I know how to add a web reference, as I said I already tried. The WCF generated the reference with `SoapTypeAttribute`

Comment: What is your service client class inherited from?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39682/discussion-between-daniel-leiszen-and-giacomo-tagliabue)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you want to consider an alternative to that encoding if possible, see: 
http://security-world.blogspot.dk/2005/07/nt-aspnet-rcpencoded-web-service-dos.html

I believe the answer you're searching for is in this post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/51babae5-26e5-4405-b03c-4301710854c0/why-does-add-service-reference-fail-to-build-a-proper-reference-for-dfa?forum=wcf

Corrected link above, don't know why the wrong one got in there

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change how the wsdl is generated.

Comment: Hi Giacomo, I accidentally pasted the wrong answer link. Essentially it's a problem in the add service reference coding towards those type of services, typically java endpoints from Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks :) So nothing we can do about it?

Comment: Your're welcome :) Using SvcUtil to generate the proxy instead essentially can be done. See for instance: http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/WCF_Essentials%E2%80%94Generating_the_Proxy

Comment: Unfortunately `Add service reference` uses `svcutil` under the hood, so the generated code doesn't change so much, especially where it should address the problem, I already tried.

Comment: Hm, just found a specific article which suggested there be a difference specifically towards those kind of java services when using the build in wrapping and the svcutil.exe, but you can follow the link and maybe it's wrong :). Have you tried specifying the collection mappings directly? Often times WCF proxies error on this little lit corner of collections and list specifically: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/09eefbbc-bf63-4aa3-a0cb-01a9dbd7f496/problem-sharing-custom-collection-types-between-service-and-client

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see, something is wrong in `SOAPItemRevisionHeadResult` type definition in th WSDL.

```
<complexType name="SOAPItemRevisionHeadResult">
  <sequence>
    <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="comment" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="searchComplete" type="xsd:boolean"/>
    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="search" type="tns2:StringMap"/>
    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="resultList" type="tns2:SOAPItemRevisionHead"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

A type with this definition maps to:

```
Public class SOAPItemRevisionHeadResult{

    public string comment;
    public boolean searchComplete;
    public Stringmap[] search;  
    public SOAPItemRevisionHead[] resultList;
}

Public class StringMap{
//can't see definition of this type in your part of WSDL posted but doesn't matter.
//guesed definition by looking at the response
    public string StringKey;
    public string StrigValue;
//end of guesed definition
}

Public class SOAPItemRevisionHead{
  //can't see definition of this type in your part of WSDL posted but doesn't matter.
  //guesed definition by looking at the response
    public StringMap[] search;
  //end of guesed definition
}
```

Seems bad nesting classes in `WSDL` but in the `Raw Response` you posted I can see the correct nesting:

```
Public class SOAPItemRevisionHeadResult{

    public string comment;
    public boolean searchComplete;
    public resultList as SOAPItemRevisionHead[]; 
}

Public class SOAPItemRevisionHead{

    public StringMap[] search;
}

Public class StringMap{

    public string StringKey;
    public string StrigValue;
}
```

Comment: So, what should I do?

Comment: Both The `SOAPItemRevisionHeadResult` and the `SOAPItemRevisionHead` has an array of `StringMap` which is called `search`. In the raw response I posted simply the `SOAPItemRevisionHeadResult` had an empty `search` array